# First post review audit failed

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I failed review audit when reviewing the following post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12847783

I commented something similar to - `"Did you try? What was the result?"`, since the question doesn't convey that the OP even tried to see if the `for` loop ends. I have been barred from reviewing for 2 days. This comment seems fair and I don't think the ban was justified.

Comment: In this case I've lifted the review ban (to be fair though an 81 upvoted post in "first posts" should be suspect as posts don't get upvotes *that* quickly after first being posted - and your comment was not worth your time anyway...)

Comment: @JonClements, thank you. But the upvotes and comments are hidden from the reviewer if it is a test.